# Android Navigation Component 'Up button' opens drawer navigation

Tags: android-actionbar, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to implement a simple navigation using Navigation Component with navigation graph and navigation controller.
I have my MainActivity with actionbar with hamburger icon and app title, a drawer navigation and content area.

Content area is where I display different fragments.

Content area is first loaded with my homescreenFragment containing 4 buttons (news, events, timetable, profile) - each of them loads fragment into my MainActivity's Content area.
It works fine, the only problem is the following:
When I press **news button** and navigate from my **homescreen** to my **NewsFragment** it loads fragment OK and changes actionbar title to News. *Hamburger icon is changed to 'Up button' icon, but when I press on it, application opens Navigation Drawer as if I press on the hamburger icon instead of navigating me back to the home screen*.

**How do I make Up button to go up and not showing left navigation drawer ?**

here is my MainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    Toolbar m_toolbar;
    DrawerLayout m_drawer;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle m_toggle;
    NavigationView m_navigationView;
    NavController m_navController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        m_toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(m_toolbar);

        m_drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        m_navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_view);

        m_navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.content);

        m_toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, m_drawer, m_toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        m_drawer.addDrawerListener(m_toggle);
        //m_toggle.syncState();

        //connect actionbar icon and drawer with nav controller
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(m_navigationView, m_navController);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, m_navController);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, m_navController, m_drawer);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_drawer_view).navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


}
```

my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
                    app:defaultNavHost="true"/>

            </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

navigation graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeScreenFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeScreenFragment"
        android:name="com.mysample.meganews.Fragments.HomeScreenFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/home_screen_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_to_news"
            app:destination="@id/newsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_to_events"
            app:destination="@id/eventsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/newsFragment"
        android:name="com.mysample.meganews.Fragments.NewsFragment"
        android:label="@string/hs_title_news"
        tools:layout="@layout/news_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/eventsFragment"
        android:name="com.mysample.meganews.Fragments.EventsFragment"
        android:label="events_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/events_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

HomeScreenFragment.java file:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeScreenFragment extends Fragment {


    public HomeScreenFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_screen_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout rl_news = view.findViewById(R.id.ll_news_btn);
        RelativeLayout rl_events = view.findViewById(R.id.ll_events_btn);

        rl_news.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_to_news));
        rl_events.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_to_events));
    }
}
```

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mysample.meganews"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha11'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha11'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem was due to mixing of different APIs . Here is the right code:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
                    app:defaultNavHost="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewParent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private NavigationView mNavigationView;
    private NavController mNavController;

    private MainViewModel mViewModel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

        setupNavigation();
    }

    private void setupNavigation()
    {
        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_view);

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

//                // we need this line to handle the navigation
//                boolean handled = NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem, mNavController);
//                if (handled) {
//                    ViewParent parent = mNavigationView.getParent();
//                    if (parent instanceof DrawerLayout) {
//                        ((DrawerLayout) parent).closeDrawer(mNavigationView);
//                    }
//                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        mNavController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.content);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, mNavController, mDrawer);
        // Tie nav graph to items in nav drawer
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mNavigationView, mNavController);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        //return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.content).navigateUp();
        //return mNavController.navigateUp()  || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(mNavController, mDrawer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and fixed it with below workaround.

```
    mNavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
                                         @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {          
            if (mAppBarConfiguration.getTopLevelDestinations().contains(destination.getId())) {
                mToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Also make sure to set the click listener to ActionBarDrawerToggle as below.

```
    mToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mActivity.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigation handle this by default you do not have to explicitly handle listener for this.
In your activity override "onSupportNavigationUp"

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, drawer_layout)
}
```

and do above. It will handle back button and hamburger icon by default.